# React unit test failing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a unit test written in react jest and for unknown reason its failing. This is the test

```
  it('handles filter addition and removal', async () => {
const addNewButton = await screen.findByText('actions.addNew')

await act(async () => {
  userEvent.click(addNewButton)

  const compareDropdown = await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('dimensionDropdown'), { timeout: 5000 })
  userEvent.click(compareDropdown)

  const optionSelect = await screen.findByRole('option')
  userEvent.click(optionSelect)

  const treeSelect = await screen.findByTestId('dimensionValues')
  userEvent.click(treeSelect)

  const optionTreeSelect = await screen.findByRole('treeitem')
  userEvent.click(optionTreeSelect)

  const submitButton = await screen.findByTestId('filtersSubmit')
  userEvent.click(submitButton)

  await waitFor(() => {
    const chips = screen.queryByTestId('filterChips0')
    expect(chips).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  const chips = screen.getByTestId('filterChips0')
  const chipsContent = chips.querySelector('p') as HTMLElement

  expect(chipsContent).toHaveTextContent('Department = test-1')

  const removeButton = await screen.findByTestId('removeFilterChips')
  userEvent.click(removeButton)

  await waitFor(() => {
    const chips = screen.queryByTestId('filterChips0')
    expect(chips).not.toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
  })
```

The warning I receive it's

```
Warning: An update to DomainFilterWindow inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */
```

But can not find the reason why. It seems that I wrapped the DOM changes into act, but still receive the error for it

Comment: First, why do you use `waitFor` so many times? You can just use findBy* selectors which return a promise that can be awaited

Comment: Those were a try to see how it behaves, but even with findBy the tests don't pass

Comment: Ok and why do you wrap your whole test code in the `act` function? you should only wrap changing state code inside. Not `find*` ones for example

Comment: If userEvent.click(addNewButton) changes the state only it should be wrapped into act?

Comment: Yes. look here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act

Comment: No it should never be wrapped in act, it calls act internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use React Native testing library, so there migth be slight differences. But I am believe you have to setup a user with userEvent.setup.
user.click is already wrapped in act and it is async, so you shouldn't reWrap it and you should await it directly instead. I think the issue was that all your code was inside the act().
Also you defined 3 consts named filterChips, I don't think you want to do that.
I think it should look more like this:

```
const user = userEvent.setup();

it('handles filter addition and removal', async () => {
  renderScreen() // I don't see where you do this, but it is best practice to have it inside your test.
  
  const addNewButton = await screen.findByText('actions.addNew')
  await user.click(addNewButton)

  const compareDropdown = screen.getByTestId('dimensionDropdown')
  await user.click(compareDropdown)

  const optionSelect = await screen.findByRole('option')
  await user.click(optionSelect)

  const treeSelect = await screen.findByTestId('dimensionValues')
  await user.click(treeSelect)

  const optionTreeSelect = await screen.findByRole('treeitem')
  await user.click(optionTreeSelect)

  const submitButton = await screen.findByTestId('filtersSubmit')
  await user.click(submitButton)


  const chips = screen.getByTestId('filterChips0')
  expect(chips).toBeInTheDocument()

  const chipsContent = chips.querySelector('p') as HTMLElement
  expect(chipsContent).toHaveTextContent('Department = test-1')

  const removeButton = await screen.findByTestId('removeFilterChips')
  await userEvent.click(removeButton)

  expect(screen.queryByTestId('filterChips0')).toBeNull()
})
```